# How to modify WPF menu drop down visual?

Tags: c#, wpf, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a WPF menu:
[image: menu dropdown]

XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ContextMenu}" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                <Border Background="#FF171616" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="5" Opacity="0.0">
                    <StackPanel ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True" Margin="5,4,5,4"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Am I using the correct `x:Type ContextMenu` to alter the drop down visualization? The menu item visual is altered because I've manually changed the style. But it is the context drop down on which I want to apply visuals.

How can I modify the context drop down itself?

Here is a paint sample of what I'm after:
  [image: desired studio dropdown]

Answer (score 0):

To modify style for menu, you need to override Menu style.
Like below:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF171616" />
</Style>
```

Edit: you can actually modify the whole template also, if you like. But I think these properties should get you the visualization you are looking for.

Comment: `BorderThickness` is not recognized on type `Menu`

Comment: It is. here is MSDN reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menu.aspx.

Comment: It is being recognized now ...the XAML had something confusing the interpreter I guess. Anyway, I'm working on it. I have a custom color for the border which means I need a border brush too ...blue (`#FF057BF0`).

Comment: This is changing the Menu *bar* not the popup.

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of the current state?

Comment: I have two screen shots in the question. :) What different shot do you need?